# How do I get the same results using Mathematica?

Tags: summation, averages

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3619042/125918)

> For each $n\ge 1$ let $l_{n,i}$ and $r_{n,i}$ be the left and the
>   right endpoints of the segment $C_{n,i}$. Since the function $x^2$
>   increases on $[0,1]$ and $ l_{n,i}\le t_{n,i}\le r_{n,i}$ for each $n$
>   and $j$, we have the bounds
>
> $$S_{l,n}=\frac 1{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}} P(l_{n,i})\le \frac
> > 1{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}} P(t_{n,i})\le \frac 1{2^n}\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}}
> > P(r_{n,i})=S_{r,n}.$$
>
> Put $l_{0,1}=0$, $r_{0,1}=1$. Then for each $n\ge 0$ we have a
>   recurrence
>
> $l_{n+1,2j-1}=l_{n,j}$,
>
> $r_{n+1,2j-1}=(l_{n,j}+r_{n,j})/2-0.5\cdot 4^{-n-1}$,
>
> $l_{n+1,2j}=(l_{n,j}+r_{n,j})/2+0.5\cdot 4^{-n-1}$, and
>
> $r_{n+1,2j}=r_{n,j}$.
>
> This recurrence is a base for the following Pascal program calculating
>   the values of $S_{l,n}$ and $S_{r,n}$ up to $n=9$.
>
> ```
> program p3608100;
> const
>  NN=9;
> var
>  OFi:Text;
>  n:Byte;
>  j:Word;
>  l,r:array[0..NN,1..1 shl NN]of Real;
>  Sl,Sr:array[0..NN]of Real;
>  pow4:Real;
> begin
> assign(OFi,'3608100.txt');
> rewrite(OFi);
> l[0,1]:=0;
> r[0,1]:=1;
> for n:=0 to NN-1 do begin
>  pow4:=1 shl (n+1);
>  pow4:=1/sqr(pow4);
>  for j:=1 to 1 shl n do begin
>   l[n+1,2*j-1]:=l[n,j];
>   r[n+1,2*j-1]:=(l[n,j]+r[n,j])/2-0.5*pow4;
>   l[n+1,2*j]:=(l[n,j]+r[n,j])/2+0.5*pow4;
>   r[n+1,2*j]:=r[n,j];
>  end;
>  Sl[n+1]:=0;Sr[n+1]:=0;
>  for j:=1 to 1 shl (n+1) do begin
>   Sl[n+1]:=Sl[n+1]+sqr(l[n+1,j]);
>   Sr[n+1]:=Sr[n+1]+sqr(r[n+1,j])
>  end;
>  Sl[n+1]:=Sl[n+1]/(1 shl (n+1));
>  Sr[n+1]:=Sr[n+1]/(1 shl (n+1));
>  writeln(OFi,Sl[n+1]:10:8,' ',Sr[n+1]:10:8);
> end;
> close(OFi);
> end.
> ```
>
> A Delphi version of the program calculated the following values
>   $S_{l,n}$ and $S_{r,n}$ up to  $n=12$ and with double precision:
>
> ```
> 0.195312500000000 0.570312500000000
> 0.287597656250000 0.443847656250000
> 0.327545166015625 0.397857666015625
> 0.345483779907227 0.378686904907227
> 0.353891015052795 0.370004296302795
> 0.357947923243046 0.365882493555546
> 0.359938955400139 0.363875722978264
> 0.360925024753669 0.362885779148201
> 0.361415686458713 0.362394156307346
> 0.361660422664158 0.362149180751317
> 0.361782641930041 0.362026901764331
> 0.361843714331917 0.361965814446739
> ```
>
> Since $38/105= 0.36 (190476)$, these calculations confirm the
>   [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606504/find-the-average-of-p-defined-on-the-fat-cantor-set/3606548#3606548)
>   by Robert Israel;

---

### Question

**How do we express this code in terms of Wolfram Mathematica?**

Answer (score 3):

One way to express it is

```
Clear[j, l, n, r, sl, sr]

nmax = 12;
l[0, 1] = 0; r[0, 1] = 1;

Do[l[n + 1, 2 j - 1] = l[n, j];
  r[n + 1, 2 j - 1] = (l[n, j] + r[n, j])/2 - 4^(-n - 1)/2;
  l[n + 1, 2 j] = (l[n, j] + r[n, j])/2 + 4^(-n - 1)/2;
  r[n + 1, 2 j] = r[n, j],
  {n, 0, nmax - 1}, {j, 1, 2^n}];

ans = Table[{sl[n] = Sum[l[n, j]^2, {j, 1, 2^n}]/2^n,
    sr[n] = Sum[r[n, j]^2, {j, 1, 2^n}]/2^n},
   {n, 1, nmax}];

N[ans, 15] // Column


(* 

{0.195312500000000,0.570312500000000}
{0.287597656250000,0.443847656250000}
{0.327545166015625,0.397857666015625}
{0.345483779907227,0.378686904907227}
{0.353891015052795,0.370004296302795}
{0.357947923243046,0.365882493555546}
{0.359938955400139,0.363875722978264}
{0.360925024753669,0.362885779148201}
{0.361415686458713,0.362394156307346}
{0.361660422664158,0.362149180751317}
{0.361782641930041,0.362026901764331}
{0.361843714331917,0.361965814446739}

*)
```